# Wordpress: Add the_permalink to a link inside of a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hyperlink, permalinks

I am very new to PHP and really don't know where to start when it comes to writing it myself.

I have found this function for Wordpress which I am using:

```
function excerpt($limit) {
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read In Full</a>';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}

function content($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'[...]';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
```

}

In the above code, I have placed

```
"<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
```

into the href. It is just showing up as a string of words instead of creating a call to the posts link.

Anyone help me out??
Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling this inside "The Loop"? http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Yes, here is the code: 

`<?php
$firmnews = new WP_Query();
     $firmnews->query('showposts=2');
while ($firmnews->have_posts()) : $firmnews->the_post(); ?>
<div class="firmnews_content">
<p>
<span class="yellow"><?php Echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
<?php
    echo excerpt(20);
?>
</p>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>`

The function is creating the "Read In Full" link on the excerpt

Comment: try by replacing `the_permalink()` with `get_permalink()` . the_permalink() echos the links while get_permalink() will return it. In your case, you are appending the link, so second is preferred

Comment: Thanks for the response but no dice ><

The issue is that the PHP is not even parsing this code. It is simply being output as HTML. So the link is pointing to www.domain/<?php get_permalink();?>.com

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this exact problem, and found that sbrajesh was right — we need to use `get_permalink()`.  But it only works if you append the php properly — when I used `<?php ?>` it didn't process the php at all (just spit out the html).

Here is the working version I ended up with: `echo implode(' ', $words)."<span class='more'><a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>read more</a></span>"; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'<a href="'<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">Read In Full</a>';
```

You forgot to put ' before and after php. Hope this helps you.

Later edit:

I guess your whole code is write in php. Then I think you should try:

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'<a href="'.the_permalink().'">Read In Full</a>';
```

Hope this time will work.

Comment: Thanks for the response :D

But it's still not working. When I do that, it breaks the whole function.

Comment: That is still breaking the function ><